# Python MySQLdb, complete insert query execution, ignoring faulty inserts

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am reading a file line by line, storing the data i need in variables and then passing them in an insert statement to store them in my db row by row. When the program hits on a unicode emoticon mysql throughs the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_json.py", line 73, in <module>
    crs.execute(ins_statement,parameters)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x87\\xB5\\xF0\\x9F...' for column 'primary_geo' at row 1")
```

I have ran into several problems with the encoding so far and i solved them by setting up mysqls encoding to `utf8mb4` like this:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

and also added in my code :

```
conn.set_character_set('utf8')
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

However, things like unicode emoticons come up, and who knows what else is going to happen while importing and parsing millions of lines. So i would like to allow 
`cursor.execute(insert_stmnt)` to add all proper lines and ignore the faulty ones, since i only need to store a sample of my raw data.

I tried :

```
` try:
      crs.execute(insert_stmnt,args)
  except (MySQLdb.Error):
      continue`
```

but this just completes the program without writing anything to my db.

Answer (score 0):

Never work when you don't get enough sleep. Especially when you are a newbie like me. I didn't commit.

```
try:
      crs.execute(insert_stmnt,args)
      conn.commit() 
  except (MySQLdb.Error):
      continue`
```